# AngularJS (1.2.25) $rootScope.$broadcast('message',data) not being received by $scope.$on('message')

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I'm having trouble getting a $scope variable to trigger the screen to rebind. Yes, I've tried calling $scope.$apply() after assigning $scope.value = value;  Yes, I've tried calling $digest() manually after the assignment; I get the error "$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress.

So What I've done is try to get my $rootScope.$on('message'function(){}) listener to create a secondary $broadcast to all scopes to try and get to the bottom of this; however, my $scope's registration of the event is not firing and I'm thinking this might be related to the same issue....maybe not. At any rate, here's my codez.

I'd build a fiddle but it's currently blocked by network policy.

Manifest:

- [config]
- [index.html]
- [foo.html]
- [ctrl]

[config] (a couple of attempted hacks. They're marked with comments)

```
    var kata = angular.module('kata',[
        'ngRoute'   
    ]).run(['$rootScope',
    function($rootScope){
        $rootScope.$on('message:foo',function(event,data){
            $rootScope.$broadcast('message:bar',['foo1','foo2','foo3']);//send secondary msg
            $rootScope.data = data; //Hack #1: When I couldn't get $scope to rebind, I tried to use $rootScope;still doesn't rebind.
        });
    }]);

kata.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider
            .when('/Foo',{
                templateUrl: 'foo.html',
                controller: 'FooCtrl'
            });
}]);
```

[index] (nothing funny here)

```
<html ng-app="kata">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,Chrome=1"></meta>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>

        <script src="./routingConfig.js"></script>
        <script src="./controllers.js"></script>        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="view-container">
            <div ng-view class="view-frame"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[foo.html] (nothing funny here)
A couple of tests with a couple of $scope variables attached to same stuff.
Neither of these update

```
<div>
    This page is for capturing Data

    Data: {{data}}
    <hr />
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="foo in foos">
            <span>Foo Found!</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[ctrl] (created several variables on scope trying to attack this problem in different ways)

```
var kataCtrl= kata.controller("FooCtrl", 
    [        '$scope', '$http','$rootScope','$location'
    ,function($scope,   $http,  $rootScope , $location) {
        $scope.data = "Foo";
        $scope.data1 = "[placeholder]";
        $scope.foos = [];


        //fires, assigns, view does not update
        $scope.$watch(function(){
            return $rootScope.data;
        }, function(){
            $scope.foos = ['data','foo','bar','baz'];<=Assignment succeeds. View does not update
            $scope.$apply();//<=Does nothing apparent; View does not update
            $scope.$digest();//<= Console Error. Already in digest loop
        },true);


        //does not fire
        $scope.$on('message:foo',function(event,data){ //<= This never catches
            $scope.data = data; 
        });


        //fires, assigns, View does not update
        $rootScope.$on('message:bar',function(event,data){
            $scope.foos = ['data','foo','bar','baz'];
            $scope.foo1 = data.element1;
            $scope.data = "[Foos returned from $rootScope]";
            $scope.$apply();//<= Does not help. Changing to $scope.$digest() indicates already in digest loop
        });
}]);
```

So as a recap, $rootScope.$on() inside my config is firing.  It is assigning values to variables on $rootScope properly.  $rootScope.$broadcast is generating a secondary message.  The controller's $scope.$on registration of the message does not catch.The controller's $rootScope.$on registration fires and assigns values on $scope, but the view does not rebind.  Calling $scope.$apply() does not help.  Calling $scope.$digest() merely reports that a digest loop is currently running.

Scoped variables are assigned to but the view never rebinds.

What in the wide wide world of sports is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you are broadcasting 'message:bar' and listening to 'message:foo' in controller. I have made simplified version of your code. You can see thet my code emits event to root scope and gots broadcasted event in child scope:

```html
<html ng-app="kata">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,Chrome=1"></meta>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>
   
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="view-container" ng-controller="FooCtrl">
            <div class="view-frame">
            <div>
                This page is for capturing Data
                <br>
                Data: {{data}}
                <hr />
                <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="foo in foos">
                        <span>Foo Found!</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <script>
            var kata = angular.module('kata',[
                    'ngRoute'   
                ]).run(['$rootScope',
                function($rootScope){
                    $rootScope.$on('message:foo',function(event,data){
                        $rootScope.$broadcast('message:bar',['Data', 'from', 'root', 'scope']);//send secondary msg
                    });
                }]);


            kata.controller("FooCtrl", 
                [        '$scope', '$http','$rootScope','$location'
                ,function($scope,   $http,  $rootScope , $location) {
                    $scope.data = "Foo";
                    $scope.data1 = "[placeholder]";
                    $scope.foos = [];

                    $scope.$on('message:bar',function(event,data){
                        $scope.data = data; 
                    });
                    
                    $scope.$emit('message:foo');
            }]);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Note that both my rootScope and my controller's scope are registering $on('message:foo')  The rootScope's listener then broadcasts a 'message:bar' that the controller's scope is listening for.  I ended up pulling out the messaging structure and set a $rootScope.$watch on $rootScope.$data.  I then had to check existence of $scope.$parent to keep the $rootScope's pass through the watch from wiping my scoped values.  Doing this caused the view to rebind.  I'm away from my dev machine, but I'll post the corrected code tomorrow to fully document the solution to my problem.